# Uneven widths/ heights in patchwork when number of plots is less than ncol x nrow

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, patchwork

I am trying to plot a large list of plots using `patchwork` to multiple pages with the same layout as specified by `ncol` and `nrow` arguments.

But the widths and heights are not unifrom across pages when the number of plots is less than the number of regions in the `ncol` x `nrow` grid.

How to get the same widths and heights when number of plots is less than `ncol` x `nrow` ?

#### Widths in page1 and page 2 are different

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))

wrap_plots(p1, p1, p1, p1, p1, p1, ncol = 3, nrow = 2) + 
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page1") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))
```

[image]

```r
wrap_plots(p1, p1, ncol = 3, nrow = 2) + 
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page2") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))
```

[image]

#### Heights in page1 and page 2 are different

```r
wrap_plots(p1, p1, p1, p1, p1, p1, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)  + 
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page1") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))
```

[image]

```r
wrap_plots(p1, p1, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)  + 
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page2") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-23 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to fill up the list of plots for the second page with empty plots using `plot_spacer()` and importantly to wrap all plots in `free()` (requires `patchwork >= 1.2.0`):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))

page1 <- replicate(6, p1, simplify = FALSE)
page2 <- c(
  replicate(2, free(p1), simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(4, free(
    plot_spacer() +
      # Remove plot border
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = NA))
  ), simplify = FALSE)
)

page1 |>
  wrap_plots(nrow = 2) +
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page1") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

[image]

```r
page2 |>
  wrap_plots(
    nrow = 2
  ) +
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page2") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

[image]

```r
page1 |>
  wrap_plots(nrow = 3) +
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page1") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

[image]

```r
page2 |>
  wrap_plots(
    nrow = 3
  ) +
  patchwork::plot_annotation(title = "page2") &
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

[image]